# simple comment box php and mysql didn't work

Tags: php, mysql

this comment-box should send the comments to my database then show it under the comment-box but nothing happen when I submit the comment .It just show up in the database . thank you .

```
<?php
require ('connects.php');
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$submit=$_POST ['submit'];


if ($submit) { $insert=mysql_query ("INSERT INTO comment (comment) VALUES    ('$comment')" ) ;


} 


?>


<html>
<head><title>Comment Box | HelperTuts</title></head>
<body>
<form action="comment-box.php" method="POST">

<label>Comment:  </label><br />
<textarea name="comment" cols="25" rows="7"></textarea><br /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" /><br />

</form>
<hr width="1100px" size="5px" />

<?php

$getquery="SELECT comment FROM comment ORDER id DESC " ;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
{

$id=$rows['id'] ;
$comment=$rows['comment'];
echo $comment["comment"] ;


} 

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this is from a tutorial, let me tell you it is a bad one. Querying without escaping a get or post means wellcome to sql injection. Mysql inteface is deprecated please use mysqli or PDO interfaces. Additionally you do not check for your query result. It may fail.

Answer (score 2):

You weren't running a query. You just constructed the SQL and left it as a string. Also, it is ORDER BY, not ORDER:

```
<?php

$getquery = "SELECT id, comment FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC ";
$result = mysql_query($getquery) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

    $id=$rows['id'] ;
    $comment=$rows['comment'];
    echo $comment["comment"] ;


} 

?>
```

Comment: And your query should select `id` as well as `comment` since you ask for it later.

Comment: @Andrew Didn't even notice that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let me take a stab at it :)

```
<?php
$mysqli=Mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","DATABASE_PASSWORD","DATABASE_NAME");

$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$comment=$mysqli->real_escape_string($comment);
$submit=$_POST ['submit'];

if ($submit) {
    $insert=$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `comment`(`comment`) VALUES('".$comment."')");
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Comment Box | HelperTuts</title></head>
<body>
<form action="comment-box.php" method="post">
<label>Comment:  </label><br />
<textarea name="comment" cols="25" rows="7"></textarea><br /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" /><br />
</form>
<hr width="1100px" size="5px" />
<?php
$getquery="SELECT `comment` FROM `comment` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result=$mysqli->query($getquery);
while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc($getquery)) {
    $id=$rows['id'] ;
    $comment=$rows['comment'];
    echo $comment["comment"] ;
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```